# Is there an m4a field editor that can run in a shell script?

Tags: ksh, m4a

I have a ksh script that will extract m4a files from various locations.  These files are actually bookmarks that point to locations within caf files.  One field contains the path to its file.  The problem is I've moved the caf files to a new drive and need to edit the path.  I can do this one file at a time in something like kid3, but I have almost 9000 and I want to just pipe file names to an in-line command and edit the particular field.  This just requires one entry in the path to be changed -- OldHD to NewHD.

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q seems  more appropriate for [softwarerecs.se] or [unix.se] , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: But you might be able to do this with a `sed` script, unless you `.m4a` files are really XML/HTML  type structures. You'll have to post a small set of sample data for your Q as well as expected output and your attempts to solve for this Q to be on-topic for StackOverflow. Also check out [mcve]. Good luck.